# Connecting Webpack and Socket Server to electron preload scripts

Tags: sockets, webpack, electron

I am working on a standalone desktop app and seemed to have hit a road block. I can successfully compile and run my electron/vue application in electron however I still manually have to run the webpack server, and socket server in another terminal. I would like to know the best way to run all services all at once or in the background.

Here is my current main.js for electron:

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron');
const path = require('path')

let win = null;

//initialize 
app.on('ready', function () {

  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1000, 
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      //this doesn't work currently
      preload: path.resolve(__dirname, "./config/socketServer.js")
    }
  });

  win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');

  win.openDevTools();

  win.on('closed', function () {
    win = null;
  });
});

//subsequent initializations
app.on('activate', () => {
  if (win === null) {
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 1000, height: 600});

  win.loadURL('http://localhost:3000');

  win.on('closed', function () {
    win = null;
  });
  }
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

package.json scripts:

```js
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "server": "nodemon ./config/server.js --watch",
    "socket": "nodemon ./config/socketServer.js --watch",
    "start": "electron .",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "node build/build.js",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
  },
```

and webpack.dev.conf:

````js
'use strict'
const utils = require('./utils')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const config = require('../config')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const path = require('path')
const baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin')
const portfinder = require('portfinder')

const HOST = process.env.HOST
const PORT = process.env.PORT && Number(process.env.PORT)

const devWebpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({ sourceMap: config.dev.cssSourceMap, usePostCSS: true })
  },
  // cheap-module-eval-source-map is faster for development
  devtool: config.dev.devtool,

  // these devServer options should be customized in /config/index.js
  devServer: {
    clientLogLevel: 'warning',
    historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /.*/, to: path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, 'index.html') },
      ],
    },
    hot: true,
    contentBase: false, // since we use CopyWebpackPlugin.
    compress: true,
    host: HOST || config.dev.host,
    port: PORT || config.dev.port,
    open: config.dev.autoOpenBrowser,
    overlay: config.dev.errorOverlay
      ? { warnings: false, errors: true }
      : false,
    publicPath: config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    proxy: config.dev.proxyTable,
    quiet: true, // necessary for FriendlyErrorsPlugin
    watchOptions: {
      poll: config.dev.poll,
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': require('../config/dev.env')
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(), // HMR shows correct file names in console on update.
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    // https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true
    }),
    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.dev.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

module.exports = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  portfinder.basePort = process.env.PORT || config.dev.port
  portfinder.getPort((err, port) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err)
    } else {
      // publish the new Port, necessary for e2e tests
      process.env.PORT = port
      // add port to devServer config
      devWebpackConfig.devServer.port = port

      // Add FriendlyErrorsPlugin
      devWebpackConfig.plugins.push(new FriendlyErrorsPlugin({
        compilationSuccessInfo: {
          messages: [`Your application is running here: http://${devWebpackConfig.devServer.host}:${port}`],
        },
        onErrors: config.dev.notifyOnErrors
        ? utils.createNotifierCallback()
        : undefined
      }))

      resolve(devWebpackConfig)
    }
  })
})```
````

Comment: I was able to work around the webpack issue, by building and loading the bundled index.html as a file `win.loadURL(file://${__dirname}/dist/index.html)`. 

That works great, however the socketserver has been another issue entirely as you can click here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59148861/socket-server-connection-error-when-run-inside-electron-desktop-app.